# Object Typecasting

Tags: java, object, typecasting-operator

In the following code:

```
A tat = new P();

P bat = (P) tat;
```

is typecasting `tat`:  `P bat = (P) tat;`

the same as saying:  `P tat = new P();`

Can you also say in theory that:  `P bat = ( P tat = new P(); )`

Comment: It's the same except that `tat` will be specifically a `P` instead of a presumably more general `A`.

Comment: `bat` will be a `P` in both cases. You won't need to downcast to assign `tat` to `bat`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes but `P bat = ( P tat = new P(); )` is not valid Java code and would not compile.

You would have to define them using two statements:

```
P bat, tat;
bat = tat = new P();
```

Comment: Or actually have it in the same line: `P bat, tat = bat = new P();`

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you need to keep in mind that while `tat` is really an instance of `P`, it has the interface defined by `A` (assuming that `P` extends or implements `A`, otherwise this wouldn't work).

Following that, `bat` will be a reference to the same object that `tat` refers to, however it will be accessible through the interface defined by `P`.

Comment: Yes, sorry P does extend A in my example.